# Selecting distinct values of column failing in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, distinct

I have a created a dataframe using spark.sql that has values like below:

```python
obj_ds = spark.sql(obj_sql)
obj_ds.show(5)

+----------+-----------+-----------+
|  obj_type|       lat2|       lon2|
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|prox_24hrs|  -41.45012|147.0977983|
|prox_24hrs|-41.1914214| 146.337882|
|prox_24hrs|-41.1576422|146.1689051|
|prox_24hrs| -38.072615|145.3897115|
|prox_24hrs|-38.0641925|144.3400812|
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I am trying to select distinct obj_type from it using below commands:

```python
obj=obj_ds.select("obj_type","lat2","lon2")
obj_list=obj.select("obj_type").distinct().rdd.map(lambda row : row[0]).collect()
```

It is failing. I tried count() and show() as well instead of collect() and they are failing too with error:

```python
An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
```

The same command is working fine with other datasource that I had. Even if i run it just for some 5-10 records, it's throwing the same error. I am not able to figure out why would it fail. I tried alternate options like groupBy, but even they did not help. Why it might be failing? I am using Pyspark 2.1.0

Full error log:

```python
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-39f9709c3dd5> in <module>()
      1 
      2 obj=obj_ds.select("obj_type","lat2","lon2")
----> 3 obj_list=obj.select("obj_type").distinct().rdd.map(lambda row : row[0]).collect()

/home/mbansa001c/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in collect(self)
    807         """
    808         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 809             port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    810         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    811 

/home/mbansa001c/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/home/mbansa001c/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/home/mbansa001c/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 39.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 39.0 (TID 428, ebdp-avdc-d233p.sys.comcast.net, executor 2): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.hasNext(SerDeUtil.scala:117)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:504)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1951)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:269)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1958)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.hasNext(SerDeUtil.scala:117)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:504)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1951)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:269)
```

Comment: Please include the full error trace and the code that created the data frame.

Comment: What happens if you do `obj_list = obj.select("obj_type").distinct().collect(); print(obj_list)`?

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly changing this worked:

```
obj.select("obj_type").distinct().rdd
```

to>>

```
obj.select("obj_type").rdd.distinct()
```